# How I can simplify this query and preselect stocks rather then manually define

Tags: mysql, mariadb

```
SELECT uuid,name,
       (SELECT quantity FROM products_stocks WHERE product_uuid = uuid and stock_uuid='3ca5a0f3-e522-11eb-84ff-2cf05dcbfb6f') AS '3ca5a0f3-e522-11eb-84ff-2cf05dcbfb6f',
(SELECT quantity FROM products_stocks WHERE product_uuid = uuid and stock_uuid='4641bb5c-e615-11eb-84ff-2cf05dcbfb6f') AS '4641bb5c-e615-11eb-84ff-2cf05dcbfb6f',
(SELECT quantity FROM products_stocks WHERE product_uuid = uuid and stock_uuid='7be9468e-a0da-11eb-84ff-2cf05dcbfb6f') AS '7be9468e-a0da-11eb-84ff-2cf05dcbfb6f',
(SELECT quantity FROM products_stocks WHERE product_uuid = uuid and stock_uuid='822e8e40-e617-11eb-84ff-2cf05dcbfb6f') AS '822e8e40-e617-11eb-84ff-2cf05dcbfb6f',
(SELECT quantity FROM products_stocks WHERE product_uuid = uuid and stock_uuid='90070678-e617-11eb-84ff-2cf05dcbfb6f') AS '90070678-e617-11eb-84ff-2cf05dcbfb6f',
(SELECT quantity FROM products_stocks WHERE product_uuid = uuid and stock_uuid='997808b0-e617-11eb-84ff-2cf05dcbfb6f') AS '997808b0-e617-11eb-84ff-2cf05dcbfb6f',
(SELECT quantity FROM products_stocks WHERE product_uuid = uuid and stock_uuid='a45d439d-4e74-11ec-8502-2cf05dcbfb6f') AS 'a45d439d-4e74-11ec-8502-2cf05dcbfb6f',
(SELECT quantity FROM products_stocks WHERE product_uuid = uuid and stock_uuid='a4c4caba-e51a-11eb-84ff-2cf05dcbfb6f') AS 'a4c4caba-e51a-11eb-84ff-2cf05dcbfb6f',
(SELECT quantity FROM products_stocks WHERE product_uuid = uuid and stock_uuid='c678beaf-1c65-11ec-84ff-2cf05dcbfb6f') AS 'c678beaf-1c65-11ec-84ff-2cf05dcbfb6f',
(SELECT sum(quantity) FROM products_stocks WHERE product_uuid = uuid GROUP by product_uuid) AS 'total'
FROM ( SELECT uuid,name FROM products where hidden=0) AS u;
```

I need to first select all stocks whene hidden=0 and then select quantity for each stock in pivot table, column names must be stocks.uuid

Now I manually defined all needed stocks but it's bad way )

sql fiddle with create and data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c4a5d03/1

Comment: You would need dynamic sql for this see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html for syntax and examples. You should also use conditional aggregation/pivot to to acquire quantity -search for mysql pivot there are lots of examples out there.

Comment: If you want an answer tailored to your specific requirement you should provide table definitions, sample data and expected outcome as text please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: pleas post the create of the table and some sample data (INSERTS)

Comment: added sql fiddle with schema and data

Comment: why the collumn 1351467d-be24-11eb-84ff-2cf05dcbfb6f ist not in your result ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

realized it as advised in comments:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT('(SELECT quantity FROM products_stocks WHERE product_uuid = uuid and stock_uuid=''',uuid,''') AS ''',uuid,'''')) INTO @sql FROM stocks where hidden=0;
        SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT id as source_id, name,name as _name,slug,thumbnail,price,',@sql,',(SELECT sum(quantity) FROM products_stocks WHERE product_uuid = uuid GROUP by product_uuid) AS total FROM ( SELECT id,uuid,name,slug,thumbnail,price FROM products where hidden=0) AS u having total>0');
        PREPARE stmt1 FROM @sql;
    
    EXECUTE stmt1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a query like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
GROUP_CONCAT("SUM(IF(ps.`stock_uuid` = '"
            , ps.`stock_uuid`
            , "'"
            , " ,ps.`quantity`,0 )) AS '",ps.`stock_uuid`,"'") INTO @dyncols
FROM ( SELECT uuid,NAME FROM products WHERE hidden=0) AS u
INNER JOIN `products_stocks` AS ps ON u.`uuid` = ps.`product_uuid`;



SET @sql = CONCAT("SELECT p.uuid,p.name,",@dyncols,", SUM(ps.`quantity`) AS total FROM ( SELECT uuid,NAME FROM products WHERE hidden=0) AS p
LEFT JOIN `products_stocks` AS ps ON p.`uuid` = ps.`product_uuid`
GROUP BY p.`uuid`");

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

**sample**

```
MariaDB [test]> SELECT DISTINCT 
    -> GROUP_CONCAT("SUM(IF(ps.`stock_uuid` = '"
    -> , ps.`stock_uuid`
    -> , "'"
    -> , " ,ps.`quantity`,0 )) AS '",ps.`stock_uuid`,"'") INTO @dyncols
    -> FROM ( SELECT uuid,NAME FROM products WHERE hidden=0) AS u
    -> INNER JOIN `products_stocks` AS ps ON u.`uuid` = ps.`product_uuid`;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.005 sec)

MariaDB [test]> 
MariaDB [test]> 
MariaDB [test]> 
MariaDB [test]> SET @sql = CONCAT("SELECT p.uuid,p.name,",@dyncols,", SUM(ps.`quantity`) AS total FROM ( SELECT uuid,NAME FROM products WHERE hidden=0) AS p
    "> LEFT JOIN `products_stocks` AS ps ON p.`uuid` = ps.`product_uuid`
    "> GROUP BY p.`uuid`");
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [test]> 
MariaDB [test]> PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.001 sec)
Statement prepared

MariaDB [test]> EXECUTE stmt;
+--------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+-------+
| uuid                                 | NAME                                                                                                        | 1351467d-be24-11eb-84ff-2cf05dcbfb6f | 3ca5a0f3-e522-11eb-84ff-2cf05dcbfb6f | 4641bb5c-e615-11eb-84ff-2cf05dcbfb6f | 7be9468e-a0da-11eb-84ff-2cf05dcbfb6f | 822e8e40-e617-11eb-84ff-2cf05dcbfb6f | 90070678-e617-11eb-84ff-2cf05dcbfb6f | 997808b0-e617-11eb-84ff-2cf05dcbfb6f | a45d439d-4e74-11ec-8502-2cf05dcbfb6f | a4c4caba-e51a-11eb-84ff-2cf05dcbfb6f | c678beaf-1c65-11ec-84ff-2cf05dcbfb6f | 1351467d-be24-11eb-84ff-2cf05dcbfb6f | 3ca5a0f3-e522-11eb-84ff-2cf05dcbfb6f | 4641bb5c-e615-11eb-84ff-2cf05dcbfb6f | 7be9468e-a0da-11eb-84ff-2cf05dcbfb6f | 822e8e40-e617-11eb-84ff-2cf05dcbfb6f | 90070678-e617-11eb-84ff-2cf05dcbfb6f | 997808b0-e617-11eb-84ff-2cf05dcbfb6f | a45d439d-4e74-11ec-8502-2cf05dcbfb6f | a4c4caba-e51a-11eb-84ff-2cf05dcbfb6f | c678beaf-1c65-11ec-84ff-2cf05dcbfb6f | total |
+--------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+-------+
| 1365caa1-e068-11eb-84ff-2cf05dcbfb6f | Сахар кусковой 1 кг Чайкофский                                                                              |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |  NULL |
| 175a2e7a-e084-11eb-84ff-2cf05dcbfb6f | Макароны из твердых сортов пшеницы перья 400 г ALTALIA                                                      |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |  NULL |
| 1f3c3f75-c9b4-11eb-84ff-2cf05dcbfb6f | Бытовая зажигалка пьезо                                                                                     |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |  NULL |
| 1f94a583-c9b3-11eb-84ff-2cf05dcbfb6f | Батарейки пальчиковые АА 4 шт Luxlite Shock                                                                 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |  NULL |
| 22b9f167-e071-11eb-84ff-2cf05dcbfb6f | Сахар тростниковый демерара светлый 500 г Брауни                                                            |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |  NULL |
| 25321456-ca9d-11eb-84ff-2cf05dcbfb6f | Влажные салфетки антибактериальные 15 шт Belux                                                              |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |  NULL |
| 2cce5997-e070-11eb-84ff-2cf05dcbfb6f | Сахар-песок белый 900 г Чайкофский                                                                          |                                  288 |                                   34 |                                   38 |                                   32 |                                   37 |                                   36 |                                   30 |                                   10 |                                   60 |                                  195 |                                  288 |                                   34 |                                   38 |                                   32 |                                   37 |                                   36 |                                   30 |                                   10 |                                   60 |                                  195 |   760 |
| 42487cfb-c9b2-11eb-84ff-2cf05dcbfb6f | Газ для зажигалки 20 мл                                                                                     |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |  NULL |
| 56d2d747-ce63-11eb-84ff-2cf05dcbfb6f | Бумажные полотенца 1 рулон 2-слойные белые Belux                                                            |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |  NULL |
| 5c2abd5f-dd55-11eb-84ff-2cf05dcbfb6f | Губка для посуды 5 шт Belux                                                                                 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |  NULL |
| 61ae32ba-ca9d-11eb-84ff-2cf05dcbfb6f | Влажные салфетки детские 72 шт Belux                                                                        |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |  NULL |
| 628aa141-ca95-11eb-84ff-2cf05dcbfb6f | Чай зеленый 25 пакетиков Мэтр                                                                               |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |  NULL |
| 8adad8b3-e088-11eb-84ff-2cf05dcbfb6f | Макароны из твердых сортов пшеницы рожки 400 г ALTALIA                                                      |                                  288 |                                   34 |                                   38 |                                   32 |                                   37 |                                   36 |                                   30 |                                   10 |                                   60 |                                  195 |                                  288 |                                   34 |                                   38 |                                   32 |                                   37 |                                   36 |                                   30 |                                   10 |                                   60 |                                  195 |   760 |
| 8b8d08d1-e06b-11eb-84ff-2cf05dcbfb6f | Сахар белый кусковой фигурный Mon Cafe 500 г                                                                |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |  NULL |
| a3be8062-ce71-11eb-84ff-2cf05dcbfb6f | Туалетная бумага 2-слойная 4 рулона Belux                                                                   |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |  NULL |
| ab88d303-e071-11eb-84ff-2cf05dcbfb6f | Сахар-песок тростниковый демерара светлый  900 г                                                            |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |  NULL |
| aee12091-c9b1-11eb-84ff-2cf05dcbfb6f | Презервативы classic Domino                                                                                 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |  NULL |
| b14df857-e068-11eb-84ff-2cf05dcbfb6f | Сахар кусковой 500 г Чайкофский                                                                             |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |  NULL |
| b48438bd-ca95-11eb-84ff-2cf05dcbfb6f | Чай черный 25 пакетиков Мэтр                                                                                |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |  NULL |
| b7dba1e7-c9ae-11eb-84ff-2cf05dcbfb6f | Рис Басмати Премиум 1 кг TaMashAe MIADI                                                                     |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |  NULL |
| d2ddad20-c9b2-11eb-84ff-2cf05dcbfb6f | Батарейки мизинчиковые AAA 4 шт Luxlite Shock                                                               |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |  NULL |
| e584607e-ca9c-11eb-84ff-2cf05dcbfb6f | Носовые платочки белые без аромата Belux                                                                    |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |  NULL |
| f730557a-dd53-11eb-84ff-2cf05dcbfb6f | Туалетная бумага 3-слойная 4 рулона Batist                                                                  |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |  NULL |
| ff3d8825-dd56-11eb-84ff-2cf05dcbfb6f | Салфетки хозяйственные универсальные 110шт Семья и Комфорт                                                  |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |                                    0 |  NULL |
+--------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+-------+
24 rows in set (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [test]> DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [test]> 
MariaDB [test]>
```

Comment: yes I already done in this way, thanks for reply. One questions why we need deallocate - what happend if not?

Comment: "To deallocate a prepared statement produced with PREPARE, use a DEALLOCATE PREPARE statement that refers to the prepared statement name. Attempting to execute a prepared statement after deallocating it results in an error. If too many prepared statements are created and not deallocated by either the DEALLOCATE PREPARE statement or the end of the session, you might encounter the upper limit enforced by the max_prepared_stmt_count system variable." see: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/deallocate-prepare.html

Comment: Or better, MariaDB supports [EXECUTE IMMEDIATE](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/execute-immediate/) so you can run it straight from the `@sql` user variable.